# Is it possible to add custom icons/images to Macro button in Word for Mac?

Tags: vba, ms-word

When assigning a Macro to a button on Windows, it allows you to immediately add it to the ribbon and add an icon/image to the button. Is there a way to do this from within Developer console, using VBA on a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows version, assigning a button to a macro adds it to the Quick Access Toolbar, not the Ribbon.

Word for Mac is less capable: you can assign a macro to the QAT, but you can't give it a custom icon at this time. Macros on the Mac QAT will always display a circle icon.

The most reliable way to add macros to the Word for Mac user interface is to create custom RibbonUI on the Ribbon (not the QAT) in Word for Windows, then move that template to the Mac. Here's a modern Windows utility that allows you to edit the customUI content: [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor). This allows you to put a macro on the ribbon with a custom icon. It's possible to edit the ribbon in macOS, but it's not for the faint of heart.

Using just VBA, about the best you can do is to use the antiquated CommandBars object, which will create an Add-Ins tab on the Ribbon, where your macro buttons and their icons will be visible.

Comment: Thanks John. Ultimately, I'm looking to compile all of these macros into a user friendly add-in to distribute externally and help automate the reformatting and review of certain documents. I've started building it as a web add-in in Visual Studio but am struggling with the deployment options. Can I host a web add-in outside the app store and office 365 without having a Service Provider License Agreement (SPLA)?

Comment: It sounds like you're already working in Windows, so you should be able to create the RibbonUI for your add-in with no problem. Here is Microsoft's page on alternate deployment methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: I prefer Mac but am using Windows to build it instead of Visual Studio Code as it seems there is more documentation/resources for the PC. I've reviewed that article numerous times, but don't see an option to host it on your own server. For example, if I want to give access to 10 users who would all download it onto their own personal machine, each with their own Microsoft Office user licenses, what approach would I use? Sideloading (which is indicated for testing)? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins#sideload-an-office-add-in-for-testing

Comment: I didn't say there was an option on that page to host on your own server. That's inherently insecure. Speculation: Microsoft doesn't need news stories about viruses appearing in add-ins, so they control the distribution process. Apple is even more ferocious about this with their App Store.